# How to track previous Dates using formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field

Ticket_tracking__c is a date type field and Old_register_tracking__c is a formula field.

I need the formula field like, while i am trying to change the Ticket_tracking__c field, then the prior values of Ticket_tracking__c has to saved in formula field by adding comma(,) between the values.

But here i have one condition i.e, while i am trying to change the Ticket_tracking__c field only the formula field needs to reflect. Formula field should not reflect when the other fields is getting modified.

could you please give any suggestion for this realtime task..
For Example I Need :: 1/1/2017;1/2/2017;1/3/2017 like this get from formula field.

Comment: Why don't you enable Field Tracking on that Date field

Comment: @ Rohit Mourya , Hi Rohit I am asking 
1. Create one field text type.
2. Create another one is formual field
3. in formula Field i store one value , that value will be store in previouslly created in  Text field stored.
then i insert another value put ' ; ' store next date value.. like that same

Answer (score 2):

**Formula field**, in your situation, won't serve your requirement. Formula field values don't get saved in the database, they are calculated at runtime. [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas) here explains

> A formula is similar to an equation that is executed at run time.

You need to have a field which would persist data, then to have values from another field you need to implement a **workflow** rule.

- Create a text field, lets call it `Ticket_tracking_history`
- Create a workflow on the object, your field `Ticket_tracking` reside on.
- Create an Update field action, select `Use a formula to set the new value`
- Update `Ticket_tracking_history` field by concatenating `Ticket_tracking` values.

**Sample Field update action**

`Ticket_tracking_history + Ticket_tracking`

Comment: Formula field don't hold(persist) values. They display calculated data, either from other fields or calculations, depending on the formula present in the formula field.