# How to update the Date Field custom Object Using Formula Field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have two custom fields, Tracking_record__c (Date Type) and Tracking_Update__c (Formula Date Type), both are Date Type;

If i change Tracking_record__c (1/1/2017), Update the Tracking_Update__c (get the Previous Value) then I change the Tracking_record__c (1/2/2017). get the Previous Date Value(1/1/2017). 
How to solve this problem could you please give any suggestions to me...

Comment: This is not possible with a formula field. As mentioned in an answer to your previous question here: [How to track previous Dates using formula field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/162911/20941), formula fields don't store values. You should use a workflow rule for this instead (or just use the standard field history functionality).

Comment: @martin , I did Using Workflow, That is not a matter, i need to use formula Field ... that is a problem ..

Comment: Why do you need to use a formula field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a workflow and a field update to write the old value in a field in a date field like

```
PRIORVALUE(Tracking_record__c)
```